# DOJO - Destroy children before parent is removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor, dojo

This is my scenario,

I am having dijit TabContainer in my page and inside the TabContainer is a CKEDITOR.

The problem is when I close the dijit tab, the parent element is first removed from the DOM and then recurrsively all the children are destroyed. But in the case of CKEDITOR which is a child inside the tab, it requires the editor to be present in the DOM for it to destroy. (CKEDITOR.instances[0].destroy())

Is there a way for me to tell the tabcontainer not to remove itself from the DOM before destroying the child widgets?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try changing the tab-closing code so that it calls `widget.destroyRecursive(true)`, and clean up the DOM manually afterwards. From the `_WidgetBase` 1.9 source, by passing `true` you are influencing:

```
// preserveDom:
//      If true, this method will leave the original DOM structure
//      alone of descendant Widgets. Note: This will NOT work with
//      dijit._TemplatedMixin widgets.
```

I don't quite understand what's going on with the `_TemplatedMixin` warning, however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I listened to 'onClose' event and fired my destroy method before the parent is fired. Since I had a whole sleu of child widgets to delete from DOM I preferred onClose event.